# Custom layout not working with List view (Single choice)

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

I tried designing a custom layout with single choice list view, but choice mode is not working. Here are the relevant codes.

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean isChecked;
    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        setEnabled(b);
        isChecked = b;
        traverseAndCheck(this, b);
    }
    private void traverseAndCheck(View v, boolean b){
        if(v instanceof ViewGroup){
            int count = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount();
            for(int i = 0; i< count; i++){
                View c = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
                if(c instanceof Checkable){
                    ((Checkable)c).setChecked(b);
                }
                else if (c instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    traverseAndCheck(c, b);
                }
            }
        }
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        isChecked = !isChecked;
        setEnabled(isChecked);
        traverseAndToggle(this);
    }
    private void traverseAndToggle(View v) {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            int count = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                View c = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
                if (c instanceof Checkable) {
                    ((Checkable)c).toggle();
                }
               else if(c instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    traverseAndToggle(c);
                }
            }
        }
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

}
```

Here is the item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="userCard"
            type="com.innofied.saferyde.model.UserCard"/>

    </data>
    <com.innofied.saferyde.widget.CheckableFrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/payment_check_drawable"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/check"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_type"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/exp_date_txt">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:text="@{userCard.name}"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text='@{"**** **** **** " + userCard.last4}'
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exp_date_txt"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:text='@{"Exp.\n" + userCard.exp_month + "/" + userCard.exp_year }'/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </com.innofied.saferyde.widget.CheckableFrameLayout>
</layout>
```

If you want, I can paste the code of adapter.

I have set singleChoiceMode on the list view, what do I have to do else?
When I am clicking on the list items, the setChecked() method of the CheckableFrameLayout is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack is to use CheckedTextView in place of Checkbox. I have still not narrowed down to the reason. So I just changed the porion

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/payment_check_drawable"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
```

to

```
<CheckedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/check"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:checkMark="@drawable/payment_check_drawable"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
```

Check out the testing code [here](https://github.com/itsdebs/CustomCheckableListView)